# When should I use a generic parameter and when should I use parent class as a parameter

Tags: java

what are the differences between the two? When should I use each?

Generic:

```
public static <T extends SomeClass> void doSomething(T class)
{
}
```

Parent class as a parameter:

```
public static void doSomething(SomeClass class)
{
}
```

Comment: There is no difference, both are template static methods, one takes the template definition for the class and the other the same class but using the class name instead of the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), both the methods are effectively the same.

Such a generic would only be useful if you're `return`ing an instance of `T` from the method. A simple example would be casting an object stored somewhere to the expected type (this is unsafe, as we do no actual check if it is really and instance of `T`, but that is another story)

```
public static <T extends SomeClass> T get(String name) {
    return (T) fancyLookup(name)
}

private static Object fancyLookup(String name) { ... }
```

So to answer your question:

## What are the differences between the two?

Nothing, at runtime they are effectivly identical.

## When should I use each?

Prefer the one without generics, as said they are the same, and introducing a generic where none is needed just complicates your code.